# How to build a enum that each case return a request payload

Tags: swift

I need to make different request end point that corresponding one payload.For example end point for
getUser: payload: {}
updateUser: payload: { "age"; 10, "gender": "M"}
createdMaleUser: payload: {"age": 2, "gender": "M"}
So I guess there are two approaches

1. Create individual function for each request and hard code the payload
2. Create one function with UserPayload enum as arguments. Based on the argument retrieve the payload and make the request
   However I do not know how to initial the enum value for each case

```
extension ABC {
    public struct UserPayload: {
        var age: Int
        var gender: String
    }
}

enum RequestType {
    case getUser
    case updateUser
    case createMaleUser
    case createFemaleUser
    
    var payload: UserPayload? {
        switch self {
        case .getUser:
            return nil
        case .updateUser:
            return UserPayload(age: 1000, gender: "M")
        case . createMaleUser:
            return UserPayload(age: 2, gender: "M")
        case . createFemaleUser:
            return UserPayload(age: 200, gender: "F")
        }
    }
}

request(.getUser.payload) /// how can i make the call like request(.getUser)
func request(_ payload: RequestType) {
   ...
}
```

However, how can I do something like so when I use the enum I can do something like
`request(.getUser)` ?

```
enum RequestType {
    case getUser = nil
    case updateUser = UserPayload(age: 1000, gender: "M")
    case createMaleUser = UserPayload(age: 2, gender: "M")
    case createFemaleUser = UserPayload(age: 200, gender: "F")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to an enum for this is to instead create static constants for every predefined instance you want.

```
extension UserPayload {
    static let updateUser = UserPayload(age: 1000, gender: "M")
    static let createMaleUser = UserPayload(age: 2, gender: "M")
    static let createFemaleUser = UserPayload(age: 200, gender: "F")
}
```

This can then be used in code in a very concise way and you can skip that extra enum type completely.

```
func request(_ payload: UserPayload) {
    // ...
}

request(.updateUser)
request(.createFemaleUser)
```

Comment: can I do this if UserPayload is one struct under extension of another class?

Comment: I can’t see why not.